# Find Search Replace from landmark to landmark - including everything in between

Tags: notepad++

I have the following string

```
>gi|374638939|gb|AEZ55452.1| myosin light chain 2, partial [Batrachoseps major]
AAMGR
```

Repeating sporadically throughout my document and want to remove everything from `>gi|37463` to the `AAMGR sequence

But, I want to keep the blocks where `JQ250` appears:

```
>gi|374638936|gb|**JQ250**332.1| Batrachoseps major isolate b voucher DBW5974 myosin light chain 2 gene, partial cds
GCNGCCATGGGTAAGTGAACGCGCCGGACCAGACCATTCACTGCATGCAATGGGGGCGTTTGTGGGTTGG
AAGGTGTGCCAAAGATCTAGGGAACCCCAACTCCTCAGGATACGGGTGGGAGCCCTAAAATATGTCCAGC
TATAAGGAGATGACCAATGGAAAAGGGGGTATCAGCAGTACTTTACCTGCTACTATAAGAGAATTGCATC
CTGGGAATAGCCTCTGAAAGGTCCCATTTTAGCGACACTGGTAGATGGACACTGGCCTTTGGACAGCACC
AGTAAGTAGAGCATTGCATCTTGGGATTCCTTTGCTGTTCACATGCCACTGAAAGCTCTCACCATAGCAG
ATTCAAAATGCCTACCCGGCAGGTTGCCAGAAAAGCACTGCATCATGGGAGAACCACTTTTAGTGACAAT
TCTAAGAGATGGGTGTCTCTCTGCCAGGCGCTATTATCCAGAGACCCCAGTATGACGTCGTCATTGCTCC
CAGGTAACCATGTTCTCACCCCCTCTCCCACAGGCCGC
```

And remove only the lines that have `AEZ554`

```
>gi|374638939|gb|**AEZ554**52.1| myosin light chain 2, partial [Batrachoseps major]
AAMGR
```

So, ideally the following block:

```
>gi|374638934|gb|JQ250331.1| Batrachoseps major isolate a voucher DBW5974 myosin light chain 2 gene, partial cds
GCNGCCATGGGTAAGTGAACGCGCCGGACCAGACCATTCACTGCATGCAATGGGGGCGTTTGTGGGTTGG
AAGGTGTGCCAAAGATCTAGGGAACCCCAACTCCTCAGGATACGGGTGGGAGCCCTAAAATATGTCCAGC
TATAAGGAGATGACCAATGGAAAAGGGGGTATCAGCAGTACTTTACCTGCTACTATAAGAGAATTGCATC
CTGGGAATAGCCTCTGAAAGGTCCCATTTTAGCGACACTGGTAGATGGACACTGGCCTTTGGACAGCACC
AGTAAGTAGAGCATTGCATCTTGGGATTCCTTTGCTGTTCACATGCCACTGAAAGCTCTCACCATAGCAG
ATTCAAAATGCCTACCCGGCAGGTTGCCAGAAAAGCACTGCATCATGGGAGAACCACTTTTAGTGACAAT
TCTAAGAGATGGGTGTCTCTCTGCCAGGCGCTATTATCCAGAGACCCCAGTATGACGTCGTCATTGCTCC
CAGGTAACCATGTTCTCACCCCCTCTCCCACAGGCCGC

>gi|374638935|gb|AEZ55450.1| myosin light chain 2, partial [Batrachoseps major]
AAMGR

>gi|374638936|gb|JQ250332.1| Batrachoseps major isolate b voucher DBW5974 myosin light chain 2 gene, partial cds
GCNGCCATGGGTAAGTGAACGCGCCGGACCAGACCATTCACTGCATGCAATGGGGGCGTTTGTGGGTTGG
AAGGTGTGCCAAAGATCTAGGGAACCCCAACTCCTCAGGATACGGGTGGGAGCCCTAAAATATGTCCAGC
TATAAGGAGATGACCAATGGAAAAGGGGGTATCAGCAGTACTTTACCTGCTACTATAAGAGAATTGCATC
CTGGGAATAGCCTCTGAAAGGTCCCATTTTAGCGACACTGGTAGATGGACACTGGCCTTTGGACAGCACC
AGTAAGTAGAGCATTGCATCTTGGGATTCCTTTGCTGTTCACATGCCACTGAAAGCTCTCACCATAGCAG
ATTCAAAATGCCTACCCGGCAGGTTGCCAGAAAAGCACTGCATCATGGGAGAACCACTTTTAGTGACAAT
TCTAAGAGATGGGTGTCTCTCTGCCAGGCGCTATTATCCAGAGACCCCAGTATGACGTCGTCATTGCTCC
CAGGTAACCATGTTCTCACCCCCTCTCCCACAGGCCGC

>gi|374638937|gb|AEZ55451.1| myosin light chain 2, partial [Batrachoseps major]
AAMGR

>gi|374638938|gb|JQ250333.1| Batrachoseps major isolate a voucher MVZ:Herp:249023 myosin light chain 2 gene, partial cds
GCCGCCATGGGTAAGTGAACGCGCCGGACCAGACCATTCACTGCCTGCAATGGGGGTGTTTGTGGGTTGG
AAGGTGTGCCAAAGATCTAGGGAACCCCAACTCCTCAGGATACGGGTGGGAGCCCTAAAATATGTCCAGC
TATAAGGAGATGACCAATGGAAAAGGGGGTATCAGCAGTACTTTACTTGCTACTATAAGAGAATTGCATC
CTGGGAATAGCCTCTGAAAGGTCCCATTTTAGCGACACTGGTAGATGGACACTGGCCTTTGGACAGCACC
AGTAAGTAGAGCATTGCATCTTGGGATTCCTTTGCTGTTCACATGCCACTGAAAGCTCTCACCATAGCAG
ATTCAAAATGCCTACCCGGCAGGTTGCCAGAAAAGCACTGCATCATGGGAGAACCACTTTTAGTGACAAT
CCTAAGAGATGGGTGTCTCTCTGCCAGGCGCTATTATCCAAGAGACCCCAGTATGACGTCGTCATTGCTC
CCAGGTAACCATGTTCTCACCCCCTCTCCCACAGGCCGC

>gi|374638939|gb|AEZ55452.1| myosin light chain 2, partial [Batrachoseps major]
AAMGR
```

Would be left as just

```
>gi|374638934|gb|JQ250331.1| Batrachoseps major isolate a voucher DBW5974 myosin light chain 2 gene, partial cds
GCNGCCATGGGTAAGTGAACGCGCCGGACCAGACCATTCACTGCATGCAATGGGGGCGTTTGTGGGTTGG
AAGGTGTGCCAAAGATCTAGGGAACCCCAACTCCTCAGGATACGGGTGGGAGCCCTAAAATATGTCCAGC
TATAAGGAGATGACCAATGGAAAAGGGGGTATCAGCAGTACTTTACCTGCTACTATAAGAGAATTGCATC
CTGGGAATAGCCTCTGAAAGGTCCCATTTTAGCGACACTGGTAGATGGACACTGGCCTTTGGACAGCACC
AGTAAGTAGAGCATTGCATCTTGGGATTCCTTTGCTGTTCACATGCCACTGAAAGCTCTCACCATAGCAG
ATTCAAAATGCCTACCCGGCAGGTTGCCAGAAAAGCACTGCATCATGGGAGAACCACTTTTAGTGACAAT
TCTAAGAGATGGGTGTCTCTCTGCCAGGCGCTATTATCCAGAGACCCCAGTATGACGTCGTCATTGCTCC
CAGGTAACCATGTTCTCACCCCCTCTCCCACAGGCCGC

>gi|374638936|gb|JQ250332.1| Batrachoseps major isolate b voucher DBW5974 myosin light chain 2 gene, partial cds
GCNGCCATGGGTAAGTGAACGCGCCGGACCAGACCATTCACTGCATGCAATGGGGGCGTTTGTGGGTTGG
AAGGTGTGCCAAAGATCTAGGGAACCCCAACTCCTCAGGATACGGGTGGGAGCCCTAAAATATGTCCAGC
TATAAGGAGATGACCAATGGAAAAGGGGGTATCAGCAGTACTTTACCTGCTACTATAAGAGAATTGCATC
CTGGGAATAGCCTCTGAAAGGTCCCATTTTAGCGACACTGGTAGATGGACACTGGCCTTTGGACAGCACC
AGTAAGTAGAGCATTGCATCTTGGGATTCCTTTGCTGTTCACATGCCACTGAAAGCTCTCACCATAGCAG
ATTCAAAATGCCTACCCGGCAGGTTGCCAGAAAAGCACTGCATCATGGGAGAACCACTTTTAGTGACAAT
TCTAAGAGATGGGTGTCTCTCTGCCAGGCGCTATTATCCAGAGACCCCAGTATGACGTCGTCATTGCTCC
CAGGTAACCATGTTCTCACCCCCTCTCCCACAGGCCGC

>gi|374638938|gb|JQ250333.1| Batrachoseps major isolate a voucher MVZ:Herp:249023 myosin light chain 2 gene, partial cds
GCCGCCATGGGTAAGTGAACGCGCCGGACCAGACCATTCACTGCCTGCAATGGGGGTGTTTGTGGGTTGG
AAGGTGTGCCAAAGATCTAGGGAACCCCAACTCCTCAGGATACGGGTGGGAGCCCTAAAATATGTCCAGC
TATAAGGAGATGACCAATGGAAAAGGGGGTATCAGCAGTACTTTACTTGCTACTATAAGAGAATTGCATC
CTGGGAATAGCCTCTGAAAGGTCCCATTTTAGCGACACTGGTAGATGGACACTGGCCTTTGGACAGCACC
AGTAAGTAGAGCATTGCATCTTGGGATTCCTTTGCTGTTCACATGCCACTGAAAGCTCTCACCATAGCAG
ATTCAAAATGCCTACCCGGCAGGTTGCCAGAAAAGCACTGCATCATGGGAGAACCACTTTTAGTGACAAT
CCTAAGAGATGGGTGTCTCTCTGCCAGGCGCTATTATCCAAGAGACCCCAGTATGACGTCGTCATTGCTC
CCAGGTAACCATGTTCTCACCCCCTCTCCCACAGGCCGC
```

Answer (score 3):

First step: make sure you are running the latest version of Notepad++ (should work on 6 or greater, tested on 6.1.8) - thanks to [Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) for this. You can use the "Regular expression" mode of notepad++'s find and replace dialog to remove the text between two markers.

To match all lines that begin with `>gi|37463` and end with `AAMGR`, put this in your "Find what:" box `>gi\|37463.*AAMGR(\r\n)?`, leave the "Replace with:" box empty, set the mode at the bottom to "Regular expression" and make sure ". matches newline" is *unticked*.

To match only the lines with `AEZ554` in them, use this search string 
`>gi\|37463.*AEZ554.*AAMGR(\r\n)?`

To match all that *don't contain* `JQ250` in them, use this search string `>gi\|37463(?!.*JQ250).*AAMGR(\r\n)?`

**Note:** might need to just use `\n` instead of `\r\n` if the file was created in unix / linux.

**Note 2:** if you want to leave a blank line in the file instead of removing the line completely, remove the `(\r\n)?` from the search term.

**Note 3:** If the question was "How do I remove lines containing `AEZ554` from a text file?" the following shell commands would work (and be faster):

on windows XP: `type oldfile.txt | find /I /V "AEZ55" > newfile.txt`

on Linux / Windows 7: `grep -v "AEZ55" oldfile.txt > newfile.txt`

Similarly, "How do I remove lines that don't contain `JQ250` from a text file?"

`type oldfile.txt | find /I "JQ250" > newfile.txt`

`grep "JQ250" oldfile.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: Does this also solve the exception that Erick pointed out?

Comment: Good point, his examples blocks didn't contain the exception so I forgot about it. I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: NP++ 6.0 and newer has full PCRE support, including negative lookaheads..